# Compute a node value from others in JSON using Node.js

Tags: node.js, calculation

I am learning Node.JS following this great [tutorial](http://www.eloquentwebapp.com/comsume-restful-api/).
It works very well however was wondering how I could derive a new column by calculating its value from others (or even the same) columns.

For example, I would like to calculate the percentage of wins vs. losses.

Would there be a way to do so through Node.Js? Or is that just not made for it? Might just be a design issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.Js is perfectly capable of handling trivial operations such as calculating percentages and the like although it's probably lacking a little bit of complex scientific modules.

Assuming you have data (Serie A 2016/2017) similar to the one described in the tutorial you mentioned.

```
table.forEach(row => {
  let lossPercentage = (row[L] / row[P]) * 100
  let winPercentage = (row[W] / row[P]) * 100
}
```

In javascript you will often deal with JSON-formatted data, in order to perform transformation on it you will use function such as map, filter, reduce. These functions are said to be functional, thus, I highly recommend you to read one or two articles about it, such as [this one](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-map-filter-and-reduce-in-javascript-5df1c7eee464)

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer! I see, will continue trying this out and reading through the link. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

This is not in relation with Node.JS in particular. This is just a mathematical problem.

Ratio:

```
wins / losses
```

Wins percent:

```
wins / (wins + losses) * 100
```

Comment: Seems you've missed my point. Question is about the Node.JS framework. I develop in C# and python and have no issue with that. Would be ashamed to ask a simple math pb :-P